Aliens secretly living among people on Earth
A movie from 1995-2000 in English, possibly US. I remember a scene from the movie. A family (or a person, I don't remember exactly) is sleeping in their car and there is a video camera recording that they forget to turn off before they sleep. After they wake up they see aliens from recordings. Then, aliens start to chase them upon realizing that they are compromised. The aliens were wearing sunglasses and sunlight hurts them.

Country\language? Approximate year? I have a vague idea, so more details would help here.

Year is like 1995-2000 , language is English and country is US i suppose. And 1 more thing I forgot to write; the aliens in the movie were wearing sunglasses and sunlight hurts them when look it.

Thanks. The extra details helped a lot. Edited the question and also posted a possible match.

The Shadow Men from 1997 with Eric Roberts and Sherilyn Fenn. From Wiki:

a married couple, Bob and Dez Wilson, and their 12-year old son Andy are being accosted by a blinding light when driving home from a daytrip. They wake up a couple of hours later seemingly unscathed but soon experience recurring nightmares. It seems that they have been abducted by aliens, as is later proved by their son's Andy's handycam that had suddenly started running right after the incident. 

The aliens, disguised as humans, don't like sunlight and wear sunglasses to hide their big alien eyes. The trailer, as well as the entire movie, are currently available on Youtube.
